# How to remove the smell of onions from hands quickly?

Tags: cleaning, smell

After cutting the onions it left bad onion smell on hands. I wash it well with a good hand cleanser it reduce the smell but did not remove the smell properly.So, how can I remove it properly very quickly. Is there any home remedy for this?

Comment: Touching a stainless-steel spoon or knife will immediately remove garlic smell from your fingertips, if you've been peeling or chipping garlic. I don't know if it works on onions, but it's worth a try.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two methods to get rid of these bad smell of onion from hands

**Method 1:**

take 1 glass of water in a bowl, put 1 table spoon of salt in it and mix it well. Then put your hands in this water for two minutes and wash with hand wash and soap.

**Method 2**

Wash your hands with vinegar or lemon juice. As lemon juice contains citric acid so it removes all type of bad smells from hands.

Answer (score 0):

Take little quantity of toothpaste and apply it both sides  of your hands,wait for two minutes and then wash it with warm water.